# Alamofire: 401 HTTP status code error handling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401

Actually I need to handle http status 401 on token expiration. I am using Alamofire in a main `class DataProvider : NSObject` and in viewControllers I am using callback function for every service.

- How can I handle response.statusCode in Alamofire function or I need to handle in every webService callback function. Please suggest me for the best approach.

Main purpose is once token expired it will auto navigate to `LoginViewController`

Alamofire Function: `DataProvider NSObject Class`

```
@objc private func getDataFromWeb(params:NSMutableDictionary,
                                callback:@escaping (_ success:Bool, _ result:Any?)->(Bool)) -> Void {
        var method = HTTPMethod.get
        var encoding = URLEncoding.default as ParameterEncoding
        if(params["Method"] as! String == "POST"){
            method = HTTPMethod.post
            encoding = Alamofire.JSONEncoding.default
        }

        var url: String!
        if (params["ServiceName"] as! String == "Function/Login") && method.rawValue == "POST" {

            url = (params["BaseURL"]!  as! String) + (params["ServiceName"]!  as! String)

        }

        if method.rawValue == "GET" {

            url = (params["BaseURL"]!  as! String) + (params["ServiceName"]!  as! String)

        } 

        var pr = params as! Dictionary<String, Any>
        pr["BaseURL"] = nil
        pr["ServiceName"] = nil
        pr["Method"] = nil
        if token == nil{ print("token nil!") }

        Alamofire.request(url,
                          method:method,
                          parameters:pr,
                          encoding:encoding,
                          headers:[ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token ?? "")"])
            .downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            //progress closure

                print(progress)
            print("Done progress bar working \(self.progressdelegate as Any)")
            self.progressdelegate?.progress(fractionCompleted: progress.fractionCompleted)
            })
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .response { response in
                 print(response.error?.localizedDescription)
                if(callback(response.data?.count != 0, response.data)){
                    self.saveDataToDB(params: params, result: response.data!)
                }else{

                }

        }


    }
```

WebService Callback - ViewController

```
func RequestData() {

        DataProvider.main.serviceGetFirmalar(callback: {success, result in
            do{
                if(success){
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseData.self, from: result! as! Data)
                    self.AppData = response.firmList

                    self.tableView.reloadData()



                    return true
                }else{
                    return false
                }
            }catch let error {
                DataProvider.main.token = nil
                print(error as Any)
                return false
            }
        })
         // End of JSON


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire's `validate` and `RequestInterceptor` APIs are designed for this use case. To implement it, you need to do a few things:

1. Add a `validate` call to your requests. This will produce an error that will trigger Alamofire's automatic retry. You're already doing this, which is good.
2. Implement a `RequestInterceptor`. This has two parts:

   1. To add your token to a request, implement the `adapt` function. This can modify your request before it goes over the network and allows you to add your token to the request after retry.
   2. To trigger retry, implement the `retry` function. In this you'll need to check the error that comes in to determine whether you need to retry. If it is, you can make a call to your token service to get a new one and trigger retry.
3. When a request is retried it will adapt its `URLRequest` again, adding the valid token, which should allow your request to succeed.

You can read more about `RequestInterceptor`s in [our documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#adapting-and-retrying-requests-with-requestinterceptor).

Comment: Thank you. Greatly explained, Let me read the mentioned documentation in detail. I want to upvote your answer but it requires 15 reputation and I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

One approach to handle this more generically, is to add an [EventMonitor](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-eventmonitors) to your Session. This way you could check all responses at once, and perhaps trigger a callback or local notification to propagate this state back to the UI:

```
class ErrorResponseMonitor: EventMonitor {
    func requestDidResume(_ request: Request) { }

    func request<Value>(_ request: DataRequest, didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value, AFError>) {
        if let httpResponse = response.response, httpResponse.statusCode == 401 {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
But my Alamofire function also provide me `.response?.statusCode` ? how can I handle this?

Comment: `EventMonitor`s are intended more as observers, not something to trigger actions from. Alamofire has specific API to handle this case.